# Bad IL Format Error: .NET Dynamic Assembly

Tags: c#, dll, runtime, .net-assembly, cil

When calling `Assembly.Load()`, I get a `BadFormatException` in my project with a message:

> Bad IL Format Error.

I am using raspberry-sharp-Io and I am trying to send the DLLs across the network and load them. I have done this in the past successfully by reading the 'bin' folder DLL files and transmitting them for loading. Although, I can add a reference at compile time just fine, the runtime version won't load even locally (much less over a network).

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Specs:
My projects are 4.5.2 and raspberry-sharp-Io is .NET 4.0. I am running on Windows 10 for my tests and currently I am running everything locally to avoid network related errors. Raspberry-sharp-Io has a GitHub page as well as a NuGet package. My running application is a XAML project.

I have simplified it to the following for testing to eliminate alternative bugs:

```
byte[] raw = File.ReadAllBytes(dependency.Location);
Assembly.Load(raw); // Exception: "Bad IL Format."
```

Comment: ...packet loss? How are you transferring the files over the network? Do you use a checksum to validate the integrity?

Comment: that's what I mentioned in the comment. I am testing all locally so thats not it. I literally read the DLL as bytes and the load. I'll ad a code example.

Comment: Do you think you could include a minimal DLL example that refuses to load?

Comment: Haha well I found the problem after I posted which sucks cause I've been looking for like two hours. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I hadn't realized that my target architecture didn't match up. This appears to have solved it now that they are both targeting x86.